# How the onChange TextField pass the data over into button onPressed property

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to pass data from `TextField` with `onChange` property to `onPressed` button.

If I type my string as below:

```
String newTextTitle;
```

then I get error on `print(newTextTitle);`:

> The non-nullable local variable 'newTextTitle' must be assigned before it can be used.
> Try giving it an initializer expression, or ensure that it's assigned on every execution path.

So I change it to

```
String? newTextTitle;
```

then the error won't appear again. But The data won't pass from `TextField` to my button, actually passing `null`.

And if I assigned some string then it is printing always what I assigned regardless of any change in the `TextField`.

My `TextField` code:

```
TextField(
 autofocus: true,
 textAlign: TextAlign.center,
 onChanged: (newValue) {
  newTextTitle = newValue;
 },
),
```

My `button` code:

```
TextButton(
 onPressed: () {
  print('Passing Test $newTextTitle');
 },
),
```

my output consol:

> I/flutter (23788): Passing Test null

This code is worked so fine in older flutter.
But now I used `Flutter 2.5.2` and there is somthing has been changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's weird works completely fine for me. Maybe match the code if you wish I can leave a sample here. Make sure you are not assigning

For the onChange function make sure you are using ``TextFormField``` instead. Although it shouldn't matter in the first place something you can try as well.

It seems like that you might be assigning string within build context and within the scope of the current text field, that's mostly the reason. A sample would be a lot helpful in that case so I can re-edit my answer for your use case.

`newTextTitle` in the scope of the build function.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return MaterialApp(
     title: 'Flutter Demo',
     theme: ThemeData(
       primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
     ),
     home: const MyHomePage(),
   );
 }
}

String? newTextTitle;

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
       body: SafeArea(
     child: Column(children: [
       TextFormField(
         onChanged: (newValue) {
           newTextTitle = newValue;
         },
       ),
       TextButton(
           onPressed: () {
             print(newTextTitle);
           },
           child: const Text('Buttom'))
     ]),
   ));
 }
}
```

Compare the code and I am on Flutter 2.5.3
[image]

```
String? newTextTitle; //past it here
Buildwidget(){
String? newTextTitle; //remove from here

}
```

Comment: I have several screens and classes.. the main which have home property goes to TaskScreen Class and this one has a float button which is calling showModalBottomSheet which is calling AddTaskScreen and there is my code.

Comment: @AbdullahBahattab just try to remove the declarative string from the current scope it put it above the scope where it can read from but it isn't in the same scope and it should be fine. You can see my last line of edit for reference.

Comment: I just move it as you suggest but got this: "This class (or a class that this class inherits from) is marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields aren't final: AddTaskScreen.newTextTitle".

Comment: its warning not error but still null. I tried your code and worked fine but mine. I believe that the declear string is the reason. but how?

Comment: @AbdullahBahattab you've moved that into a class instance that needs to be assigned into constructor maybe. Move that above one scope more.

Comment: put it above the class and its worked. like import'xxxx'; String? xy; class{} thank you

Answer (score 1):

Using a `TextEditingController` is the Flutter recommended way of doing what your trying to do. See (https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/forms/text-field-changes)

```
// Setup your controller
final TextEditingController _controller = TextEditingController();

// Add controller to your TextField
TextField(
   controller: _controller,
),

// Get the text via controller.
TextButton(
  onPressed: () {
     print(_controller.text);
  },
  child: const Text('click')
)
```